# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Tags: android, google-maps

I have checked many blogs for fixing this but it's not working.

My **main_activity.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#12ffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I added google_play_services_lib to my project.

This is my MainActivty.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GPSTracker mGpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
        if(mGpsTracker.isGPSEnabled){
            LatLng current_location = new LatLng(mGpsTracker.getLatitude(), mGpsTracker.getLongitude());
             map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
             Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current_location).title("You"));

                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current_location, 15));
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my package name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name="my package name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="my package name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="my package name.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBRPl30vkFxrStRAIxkXllTf8n8gykrCeo" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please tell me the what mistake i did here.

Comment: Check your library dependencies as well as the order in the build path.

Comment: which android-support-library do you use? i think you have to use [android.support.v4.app](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html) library